# Authenticate from active directory for remote users through SAML or WS-FED using OKTA?

Tags: active-directory, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, ws-federation, okta

We have an instance based web app on IIS which uses active directory for authentication.
This web app has an external public web address for remote users to work with.

OKTA provides Active directory integration which sync directory and provide SSO for users inside the active direcory domain.

But for remote users as far as i know OKTA can provide SSO through their SWA (secure web application) type of application but which means using a browser plugin from OKTA for remote users.

Is there any other way for us to authenticate from active directory 
for remote users through SAML or WS-FED using OKTA?

Answer (score 0):

Okta supports SAML 2.0 for this use case. Please reference the documentation at https://support.okta.com/pkb_Home?q=SAML&l=en_US for details on how to configure this.

Also note that there's a sample app demonstrating SAML integration via the Spring framework (if the app in question is Java-based). http://developer.okta.com/docs/examples/spring_security_saml.html

Comment: It is an .net based IIS web app which uses Active directory for authentication. A third party instance based web app.

Comment: There are several ways to do this including an on-prem agent that brokers connections to Okta. It's a pretty common scenario and the documentation would be a great place to get started. If you get stuck in your implementation, open another question with your specific issues and the Okta community will help out.